# Unexpected module path go-modules

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a repo on Github which just holds some Go structs to be used as models throughout my services.

https://github.com/pocockn/models

I then want to import this into my services, I am using Go Modules in both repos. When I run 'go get' in my service I get the following error.

> go: finding github.com/pocockn/models/api/football latestgo: finding
>   github.com/pocockn/models/api latest go: finding
>   github.com/pocockn/models latest go:
>   github.com/pocockn/models@v0.0.0-20190511152220-d7675ec24338: parsing
>   go.mod: unexpected module path "models"

My go.mod file in the models repo looks like this

```
module models

go 1.12

require github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.8
```

Comment: Your module is `github.com/pocockn/models` but you initialized it only as `models`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your module name in your `go.mod` should be `github.com/pocockn/models`, matching the repo path. It could also be a custom domain/path, assuming that domain either has the code hosted or the correct headers to redirect to your repo (using something like https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/govanityurls).

(Looks like you may have already done this. Answering here if others find this question.)